# I could't get rid of System.Range.get_Start Error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, system

I wanted to create a bool which controls the curious numbers but when i fill the "for" loop with long.Parse method compiler gave me System.Range.get_Start error. How can i get rid of that ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //IsCuriousNum(300);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool IsCuriousNum(long num)
{
    bool isCuriousNum = false;
    long sum = 0;

    string numS = num.ToString();

    for (long i = 0; i < numS.Length; i++)
    {
        char a = (char)long.Parse(numS[i]);
        sum += Factorial(a);
    }

    if (num == sum)
    {
        isCuriousNum = true;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());

    return isCuriousNum;
}

static long Factorial(long num)
{
    long factorial = 1;

    for (long i = 1; i <= num; i++) factorial *= i;

    return factorial;
}
```

Comment: why are you casting to `char`?

Comment: i don't know i just wanted to take one digit from the number so i thought this could  be much more effective. But no It doesn't occur that problem i tried another ways :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mentioned in the other answer(s), your `for` loop is the problem. You are trying to index a `string` with a `long` value (`numS[i]`) which is not supported. Indexing is supported only on `int` data type. What compiler is asking you is to provide a implementation for indexing over `long` -

```
for (long i = 0; i < numS.Length; i++)
{
    char a = (char)long.Parse(numS[i]);
    sum += Factorial(a);
}
```

And as you said `num` is of type `long`, however, number of digits of `num` can be maximum 19. [Int64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64?view=netframework-4.8)

> Int64 is an immutable value type that represents signed integers with values that range from negative 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 (which is represented by the Int64.MinValue constant) through positive 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (which is represented by the Int64.MaxValue constant. The .NET Framework also includes an unsigned 64-bit integer value type, UInt64, which represents values that range from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

So you can safely use `int` to interate over all the digits of `num` or `numS`.

Also, you can rewrite your `for` loop as follows -

```
for (int i = 0; i < numS.Length; i++)
{
    var a = numS[i] - 48;
    //char a = (char)long.Parse(numS[i]);
    sum += Factorial(a);
}
```

As ASCII for `0` is 48, so subtracting 48 from char `0` will give you number 0.

Answer (score 0):

change your loop to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numS.Length; i++)
{
    long a = long.Parse(numS[i].ToString());
    sum += Factorial(a);
}
```

Comment: There is another problem. Num is long value but I'm using integer for i. I guess it isn't a proper solution.

Comment: i is for indexing only. what this loop does it that it takes one digit at time (left to right), compute the factorial and add it to sum.